# загрузка файла на сервер и перемещение в папку,папка защищена от записи, рhp

Tags: php, mysql, файлы, fileupload, httpbackend

Помогите разобраться, вопрос/проблема вот в чём:

в папке `webroot/uploads/` не появляется файл который загружается на сервер, хотя путь прописан, сама функция перемещения никаких ошибок не выдает...

странность еще в том что в папке `webroot` появляется файл `$full_path`, с набором просто цифр...

сам путь в базе сохраняется всё корректно (в виде: `webroot/uploads/1496868491.png`)

решил глянуть `var_dump($_FILES['img_file'])`;

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(6) "t1.png"
  ["type"]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(50) "C:\openserver\OpenServer\userdata\temp\php5875.tmp"
  ["error"]=>
  int(0)
  ["size"]=>
  int(2387)
}
```

сам код.

```
path = 'webroot/uploads/'; // директория для загрузки
        $ext = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['img_file']['name'])); // расширение
        $new_name = time().'.'.$ext; // новое имя с расширением
        $full_path = $path.$new_name; // полный путь с новым именем и расширением
        echo "<pre>"; 
        echo var_dump($_FILES['img_file']);
        echo "</pre>";

        if($_FILES['img_file']['error'] == 0){
            if(move_uploaded_file(($_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name']), '$full_path')){,,,,}
```

В поисках решения наткнулся на совет проверить папку на запись

```
if (!is_writable($path)) {
                die("Запись в каталог запрещена");
} else {if(move_uploaded_file(....)){...}
```

Так вот проверка выдала что $path, защищен от записи, кто знает как дать разрешение на запись? (вопрос в том что можно сделать это через cmd, или же с помощью средств php)

Comment: Поменять права можно php функцией `chmod`, но результат операции будет зависеть от того, достаточно ли прав у пользователя, от которого запущен nginx/apache процесс. Но, это плохая практика. Папка для upload должна существовать и иметь права на запись изначально.

Answer (score 1):

добавил по совету (B. Bohdan) к переменной пути следующее `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].`

получилось так

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/webroot/uploads/";
```

!update! после таких манипуляций при вызове адреса картинки из базы, сама картинка не подтягивалась из дериктории т.к путь был следующего вида

C:/openserver/OpenServer/domains/localhost/webroot/uploads/1496908169.png

соответственно это не удовлетворяло конечную цель.

после редактирования получил следующий код.

```
$path = "/webroot/uploads/"; // директория для загрузки
        $ext = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['img_file']['name'])); // расширение
        $new_name = time().'.'.$ext; // новое имя с расширением
        $full_path = $path.$new_name; // полный путь с новым именем и расширением
        /*echo "<pre>"; 
        echo var_dump($path);
        echo "</pre>";*/

        if($_FILES['img_file']['error'] == 0){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$full_path)){
                // Если файл успешно загружен, то вносим в БД 
                // Можно сохранить $full_path (полный путь) или просто имя файла - $new_name
```

в моём случае всё заработало, и теперь изображения попадают в папку (C:/openserver/OpenServer/domains/localhost/webroot/uploads/1496908169.png) , а путь к ним записывается в базу в таком виде (/webroot/uploads/1496909914.png) =)

Answer (score 0):

Работа этой суперглобальной переменной зависит от правильности настроек сервера. Ее использование рекомендовано стандартом.

Comment: Рекомендовано или не рекомендовано?

Comment: Рекомендовано. Подробнее см. http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score -1):

Зачем '$full_path' в последней строке оборачивать в одинарные кавычки?
Я делаю вот так:

```
//куда загружать?
$dir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/webroot/uploads";

//имя файла (с расширением)
$name = basename($_FILES["img_file"]["name"]);

//расширение файла
$ext = array_pop(explode(".", $name));

//новое имя (с расширением)
$new_name = time() . "." . $ext;

//постоянное место хранения файла
$file_dir = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new_name;

//временное место хранения файла
$tmp_name = $_FILES["img_file"]["tmp_name"];

//переместить файл в постоянное место хранения
if (is_uploaded_file($tmp_name) && move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $file_dir)) {
    echo "Файл успешно загружен по такому адресу: " . $file_dir;
} else {
    echo "Не удалось загрузить файл по такому адресу: " . $file_dir;
}
```

А еще лучше — обратитесь к документации, там все подробно описано: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: если убрать ковычки в  '$full_path'  то, вылазят 2 ошибки...



Warning: move_uploaded_file(webroot/uploads/1496902947.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\localhost\models\seller.php on line 33




Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\openserver\OpenServer\userdata\temp\phpEC51.tmp' to 'webroot/uploads/1496902947.png' in C:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\localhost\models\seller.php on line 33

Comment: Путь лучше всего формировать с помощью $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. В крайнем случае можно использовать dirname(__FILE__) (с двумя символами подчеркивания в начале и конце FILE). Вы попробовали мой вариант? Или вам нужна именно такая структура кода, как в вашем варианте?

Comment: Ваш вариант пока еще не пробывал...